# Latest entry SQL problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

> UserTable contains (UserID, UserName) and  StoryTable contains
>   (StoryID, UserID(foreignkey), StoryName, InsertedDate)

How can I query to get each User Name along with the latest story name that he has posted ? (I m new to queries so kindly excuse if its quite basic)

I tried:

> SELECT a.Username, b.StoryName FROM [dbo].[UserTable] as A INNER JOIN
>   [dbo].[StoryTable] as b ON a.UserID = b.UserID WHERE InsertedDate =
>   MAX(InsertedDate) group by a.UserName;

but it throws error in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to be this:

```
SELECT a.Username, b.StoryName 
FROM [dbo].[UserTable] as A 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StoryTable] as b ON a.UserID = b.UserID 
WHERE b.InsertedDate = 
      (SELECT MAX(InsertedDate) FROM [StoryTable] AS z WHERE z.UserID = A.UserID)
```

---

Edited as per comment:

```
SELECT a.Username, b.StoryName 
FROM [dbo].[UserTable] as A 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StoryTable] as b ON a.UserID = b.UserID 
WHERE b.StoryID = 
      (SELECT MAX(z.StoryID) FROM [StoryTable] AS z WHERE z.UserID = A.UserID)
```

Comment: This could return an unwanted result in the unlikely event of redundant InsertedDate for the same userid. Especially if InsertedDate is defined as a date instead of a datetime

Comment: Hence it would be better to use MAX(pk) instead of date if the data is inserted with a sequential (or just increasing) primary key value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Top 1 a.Username, b.StoryName 
FROM [dbo].[UserTable] as A 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StoryTable] as b ON a.UserID = b.UserID 
order by b.InsertedDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SELECT       u.Username, s.StoryName
FROM         [dbo].[UserTable] AS u
CROSS APPLY  (SELECT TOP 1 StoryName  
              FROM         [dbo].[StoryTable] AS ss
              WHERE        ss.UserID = u.UserID 
              ORDER BY     ss.InsertedDate DESC
             ) AS s
```

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is slow. It would be much faster to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY InsertedDate DESC)` and look for where `ROW_NUMBER()` is 1

Answer (score 0):

MAX is an aggregate function, to filter using an aggregate function, you need to use the HAVING keyword instead of WHERE

Comment: i tried: SELECT a.Username, b.StoryName FROM [dbo].[UserTable] as A INNER JOIN [dbo].[StoryTable] as b ON a.UserID = b.UserID group by a.UserName HAVING MAX(InsertedDate) ; but it throws error